# How to create a mdb file with ODBC?

Tags: c++, odbc

I'd like to create a new mdb file with my program but fails with the error code 6, corresponding to `ODBC_ERROR_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND`, and the following localized message : **Composant introuvable dans le registre** which can be translated as : **Component not found in registry**.

I'm not sure what exactly is needed from the registry but the following key and its data is present in my computer:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
```

So what I'm doing wrong ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <odbcinst.h>


int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    LPCWSTR sDriver = L"Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)";
    LPCWSTR wcAttrs = L"CREATE_DB=.\\Test.mdb General\0";

    std::wcout << L"Check: " << wcAttrs << std::endl;

    SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_ADD_DSN, sDriver, wcAttrs);

    SQLRETURN sReturn;
    DWORD pfErrorCode;
    wchar_t lpszErrorMsg[256];

    sReturn = SQLInstallerError(1, &pfErrorCode, lpszErrorMsg, SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, 0);

    std::wcout << L"pfErrorCode: " << pfErrorCode << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Error message: " << lpszErrorMsg << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to use **odbccp32.lib** and **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib** if you want to compile this code.

Comment: *.accdb preferred to *.mdb in windows10

Comment: I'm not using windows 10, and it seems that MS office is needed to get the drivers for that format. To be confirmed.

Comment: MS Office is not required. For x64, you may download AccessDatabaseEngine_x64. The database can be set up as UserDNS under Administrative tools in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to create the file alone is good. What is wrong is the computer's configuration.
In the registry, the ODBC driver definitions are located at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\** for **32-bit** programs.

But **64-bit** ones look at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\** where, in the present case, are missing.

ODBC drivers are platform specific so they can be available for 32-bit applications but not for 64-bit ones on the same machine.

In my case, a x64 computer, a 32-bit MS Office suite is installed, with all the bundled 32-bit ODBC drivers. The code above fails in 64-bit mode but creates the .mdb file successfully when compiled in 32-bit mode. (Relative paths work fine BTW).

So the final solution for this issue is to download and install the ODBC drivers for x64 platform (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

No configuration is needed in the administrative tools panel since it's used to point at already existing databases.

Thanks to seccpur for pointing me at the right direction.